# Bigtable Row Based Access Control Patterns

Tags: acl, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I would like to implement row based access control for Bigtable using roles so that each row may allow one to many roles. I do not know how I could get this into the key easily.

What patterns are available for implementing something like this?

My current use case is making a prefix range lookup with my other indices as part of the key already.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, currently Bigtable does not support a native row-based ACL feature. It really depends on your use case, but there are several ways to implement this yourself. Following you will find some possible suggestions:

- [Apache Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/) is a wrapper around HBase which implements row-based ACLs.
- A proxy layer ahead of the table which queries for the "permissions" on the table itself, or a secondary permissions table is *viable*, however, quite complex to implement yourself. From what I understand, that is the solution you may have gone with, but keep in mind that the caveat is you must implement the check for complex queries as well, which might make it very inefficient (and convoluted to maintain as new features arrive).

Answer (score 0):

```
roles := []bigtable.Filter{bigtable.ColumnFilter("public"),
                   bigtable.ColumnFilter("admin")}

acl := bigtable.InterleaveFilters(roles...)

table.ReadRows(context.Background(), rr, func(r bigtable.Row) bool {
   // do something
}, bigtable.RowFilter(acl))
```